# How to phase out the json loading process to multiple steps to achieve improved user experience?

Tags: javascript, java, json, pagination, lazy-evaluation

I am using a web service that serves travel related data from third party sources, this data is converted to JSON and 
is used to formulate the output based on search criteria a user.

If the web service subscribes to multiple third party service providers, the application receives thousands of potential search results for some searches.Some of these JSON files created for these search results are as [high as 2-4 MB][1] which causes considerable delay in attempting to loading the json results.

The whole json result set is required for further sorting and filtering operations on the search results by the users.Moving the sort and filtering operations to the back-end is not a possibility as for now.

For small and medium JSON result sets the current implementation works out well but large JSON result sets cause performance degradation.

How could I phasing out the JSON loading process to multiple steps to achieve improved user experience even with very large JSON result sets?

Any leads on how I can overcome this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your last link opens Expedia. You might possibly get spam flags. I am assuming its probably a mistake. I suggest you change it.

Comment: If the 3rd party services don't have any 'paging' features then you don't have any choice but to pull back all the data from them. You can code it so it doesn't display it all to the user, but this won't stop you having to query it all from the service anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find some a way to solve this issue so i though might as well post it for other who may find this answer useful.

The web pagination mechanism will automatically improve responsiveness of the system, user experience, and may reduce clutter on the page. Unless the returning result set is guaranteed to be very small, any web application with search capabilities must have pagination. For instance, if the result set is less then 30 rows, pagination may be optional. However, if it's bigger then 100 rows, pagination is highly recommended, and if it's bigger then 500 rows, pagination is practically required. There are a lot of different ways to implement the pagination algorithm. Depending on the method used, both performance and the user experience will be affected.

***Some Alternatives on phasing out the Json loading processes to multiple steps***

If the JSON is large, you could always contemplate a "paging" metaphor, where you download the first x records, and then make subsequent requests for the next "pages" of server data. Given that additional server records can presumably be added between requests, we will have to think carefully about that implementation, but it's probably easy to do.

Another way of making the JSON more efficient, is to limit the data returned in the initial request. For example, the first request could return just identifiers or header information for all or a reasonable subset of the records, and then you could have subsequent requests for additional details (e.g. the user goes to a detail screen).

A particular permutation of the prior point would be if the JSON is currently including any large data elements (e.g. Base64-encoded binary data such as images or sound files). By getting those out of the initial response, that will address many issues. And if you could return URLs for this binary data, rather than the data itself, that would definitely lend itself for lazy loading (as well as giving you the ability to easy download the binary information rather than a Base64 encoding which is 33% larger). And if you're dealing with images, you might want to also contemplate the idea of thumbnails v large images, handling the latter, in particular, in a lazy-loading model.

***If adopting the first approach.....***

If adopting the first approach which seems more feasible given the current development scenario, you first need to change your web search result processing back end code so that in response to a request, it only delivers n records, starting at at a particular record number. You probably also need to return the total number of records on the server so you can give the user some visual cues as to how much there is to scroll through.

Second, you need to update your web app to support this model. Thus, in your UI, as you're scrolling through the results, you probably want your user interface to respond to scrolling events by showing either

(a) actual results if you've already fetched it; or 
(b) some UI that visually indicates that the record in question is being retrieved and then asynchronously request the information from the server.

You can continue downloading and parsing the JSON in the background while the initial data is presented to the user. This will simultaneously yield the benefit that most people associate with "lazy loading" (i.e. you don't wait for everything before presenting the results to the user) and "eager loading" (i.e. it will be downloading the next records so they're already ready for the user when they go there).

***General Implementation steps to follow for first approach***

1. Figure out how many total rows of data there are once merge process is complete.
2. Retrieve the first n records;
3. Send request for subsequent n records and repeat this process in the background until full result set is received.
4. If the user scrolls to a record, you show it if you've got it, but if not, provide visually cue that you're going to get that data for them asynchronously.
5. when the data comes in merge JSON update the UI, if appropriate.
6. If by any channce filters and sorting options are applied on web end they should be disabled until full result set is received.

***General Implementation steps to follow to generating page links***

After choosing the best approach to retrieve the result set and traverse it, the application needs to create the actual page links for users to click. Below is a generic function pseudo-code, which should work with any server-side technology. This logic should reside in your application, and will work with both database-driven and middle-tier pagination algorithms.

The function takes three (3) parameters and returns HTML representing page links.The parameters are query text, staring location row number, and total number of the result set rows. The algorithm is clever enough to generate appropriate links based on where the user is in the navigation path.

**Note:** I set the default of 50 rows per page, and a page window to 10. This means that only 10 (or fewer) page links will be visible to the user.

```
private String getSearchLinks(String query, int start, int total) {
// assuming that initial page = 1, total = 0, and start is 0

   String result = "";
   int start = 0;

   if (total == 0) { return "";    // no links }

   Int page_size = 50;    // number of rows per page
   //page window - number of visible pagers per page
   Int window = 10;


   int pages = ceil(total / page_size );
   result = "Pages:";

   int current_page = (start / page_size ) + 1;
   //numeric value of current page ex. if start is 51 : 51/50 =
   // 1 + 1 = 2

   Int left_link_count = ((current_page - 1) > (window / 2))
      ? (window / 2 - 1) : (current_page - 1);
   Int pageNo = current_page - left_link_count;

   if (pageNo > 1) {    // show first page and if there are more
                           // links on the left
      result += "1 .. ";
      result += "«";
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < window-1; i++) {
      if (pageNo > pages) {
         break;
      }
      else if (pageNo == current_page) {
         result += "" + pageNo + "";
      }
      else {
         result += "pageNo";
      }
      pageNo++;
   }    // end for

   if ((pageNo - 1) < pages) {
      result += "»";
   }

   result += "
Showing"+((start  > total)?total+1:start+1)+
             " - "+(((start + 50)>total)?total:(start + 50))+"
             of Total:"+total;

   return result;

}
```

This logic does not care how the viewable portion of the result set is generated. Whether it is on the database side or on the application server's side, all this algorithm needs is a "total" number of results (that can be per-cached after the first retrieval), and the indicator ("start") containing which row number was the first on the last page user was looking at. This algorithm also shows the first page link if the user is on a page beyond the initial page window (for example, page 20), and correctly accounts for the result sets with a number of rows not enough for 10 pages. (for example, only 5 pages)
The main "for loop" generates the links and correctly computes the "start" parameter for the next page. The Query string and Total are always the same values.

***Points to note***

- In a portal where internal and external data is used there would be
  an unavoidable performance overhead because the system will have to
  wait until all external hotel information is fully received and
  merged and sorted with local hotel details. Only then would we be
  able to know the exact result count.
- Deciding how many additional requests are required would be somewhat
  simplified if a standard result count per page is used.
- This change would provide the user with a quick and uniform page load
  time for all search operations and it would be populated with the
  most significant result block of the search on the first instance.\
- Additional page requests could be handled through asynchronous
  requests.
- Not only the hotel count but the content sent also needs to be
  checked and optimized for performance gains.
- Some instances for similar hotel counts for the generated JSON object
  size varies  considerably depending on the third party suppliers
  subscribed too.
- Once the successive JSON messages are received these JSON blocks
  would need to be merged. Prior to the merging the user may need to be
  notified new results are available and if he/she wishes to merge the
  new results or work with existing primary result set.

**Useful Resources :***

[Implementing search result pagination in a web application](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3696226/Implementing-Search-Result-Pagination-in-a-Web-Application.htm)

[How big is too big for JSON?](http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/)